# How to write a LINQ query resulting in a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, dictionary

```
public class Person
{
    public string NickName{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

var pl = new List<Person>;

var q = from p in pl
        where p.Name.First() == 'A'
        orderby p.NickName
        select new KeyValuePair<String, String>(p.NickName, p.Name);

var d1 = q.ToList(); // Gives List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
var d2 = q.ToDictionary(); // Does not compile
```

How to get Dictionary<string, string>?

Comment: how about `new Dictionary(d1);` or `d1 = q.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);`

Comment: @Jodrell good luck compiling that `new` statement

Comment: @Alex, you are right, there is no `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T,T>>` contructor overload.

Comment: It looks amazing to me how all the people here prefer using method syntax over LINQ syntax. Any reason why?

Comment: Because method syntax is also LINQ syntax... the one you desire as LINQ syntax is called `Query Expression Syntax` which is translated back the the `Extension Method Syntax` by the compiler... :)

Comment: I understand, @JanP. But this doesn't explain why would everybody prefer to use method LINQ syntax over Query Expression Syntax :-)

Comment: It is just about what you like most... but the method syntax has more functions then the QES... i personaly only use QES when i have to use `join` or `let`

Comment: Generally the method syntax is more terse, so takes less time to read and less time to type.

Comment: Extended my answer to give you an implicit option.

Comment: Method Syntax looks like ordinary C# code.  Query syntax looks like a blob of SQL randomly dropped in the middle of a .cs file.  Stylistically I prefer the former for giving a more consistent appearance in the source file.

Answer (score 43):

You need to specify the values for the `Dictionary`

```
var d2 = q.ToDictionary(p => p.NickName, p => p.Name);
```

Answer (score 11):

A dictionary cannot contain multiple equal keys, so you should ensure (or know) that this is not the case. You could use `GroupBy` to ensure it:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = pl
        .Where(p => p.Name.First() == 'A')
        .GroupBy(p => p.NickName)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().Name);
```

Comment: Why not `ToLookup()`? Should you order by `Nickname` in the subquery when you've already grouped by `Nickname`?

Comment: @Jodrell: Why `ToLookup`? OP asks for a dictionary explicitly. Yes, the `OrderBy` is redundant (as in OP's code). I'll remove it.

Comment: Because I can't think of a situation where discarding data because of the way its enumerated makes much sense. An `OrderBy` on the `IGrouping` might make it less arbritary.

Comment: @Jodrell: If you just want to see one and only? Apart from that it's what OP wanted (it might be better than an exception anyway). I would use an `IEnumerable<string>` as value. But maybe he wants to concat all names with the same nickname with comma: `.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => string.Join(",",g.Select(p => p.Name)));`. Who knows? The motive of my answer was to alert this issue.

Comment: I agree, an unhandled exception would be bad.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**

If you really feel you need to get from `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` to a `Dictionary` implicitly you could add this extension.

```
public static IDictionary<TKey, ToValue> ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> source)
{
    return source.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
}
```

Then you could call `ToDictionary()` on any `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

**EDIT 2**

If you are anticipating duplicates then you could create a `ToLookup()` extension too.

```
public static ILookup<TKey, TValue> ToLookup<TKey, TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> source)
{
    return source.ToLookup(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
}
```

Alternatively, if you really want to discard results, you could add an overload for `ToDictionary`.

```
public static IDictionary<TKey, ToValue> ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> source,
    Func<<IEnumerable<TValue>, TValue> selector)
{
    return source
        .Lookup(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
        .ToDictionary(l => l.Key, l => selector(l));
}
```

If you arbitrarily discard all but the "first" (what does that mean without an `OrderBy`) item, you could use this extension like this,

```
pairs.ToDictionary(v => v.First());
```

---

Overall, you can remove most of your code and do,

```
var q = from p in pl
        where p.Name.First() == 'A'
        select p;
var d = q.ToDictionary(p => p.NickName, p => p.Name);
```

If there could be duplicates, [do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211.aspx)

```
var d = q.ToLookup(p => p.NickName, p => p.Name);
```

but note, this returns an [`ILookup<TKey, TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx), the [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549314.aspx) indexer of which, returns an `IEnumerable<TElement>` so you don't discard data.

Comment: for your 2nd last code block `var q = from p in pl where p.Name.First() == 'A';` , exception `A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause` is thrown when compiled

Answer (score 5):

Try following for NickName as Key, and Name as Value

```
var d2 = q.ToDictionary (p => p.NickName, p=>p.Name);
```

But note that dictionary does not allow duplicate, so above will throw error for duplicate records with same nickname. Perhaps you would like to use Lookup that is similar to Dictionary, but allows duplicates

```
var d2 = q.ToLookup (p => p.NickName, p=>p.Name);
```

Comment: Specifying that a KeyValuePair's Key is the key and its Value is the value looks a lot like Captain Obvious's code (it should really be made implicit, IMHO) but seems to solves the problem, thanks.

Comment: making it implicit will not work for all types of sequence. It will work only for sequence over KeyValuePair, but then you would require another layer in between to produce keyvaluepair.

Comment: @Ivan but, there is actually no need to make the intermediate `List<KeyValuePair<,>>`, just you the explicit syntax on the end of your query. As in my answer. You can loose the order by too.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this was tagged with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), but I was literally **just** trying to figure out how to do this in [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) yesterday, so I thought I would share how you'd do this in VB as well:

```vb
Public Class Person
    Property NickName As String
    Property Name As String
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim p1 As New List(Of Person)

    '*** Fill the list here ***

    Dim q = (From p In p1
             Where p.Name.First = "A"
             Select p.NickName, p.Name).ToDictionary(
                                           Function(k) k.NickName, 
                                           Function(v) v.Name)
End Sub
```

Comment: But, you don't need th intermediate `KeyValuePair`s or the `OrderBy` in VB either.

Comment: That's true. I kinda just took the code from the question, converted it to VB, and then added the `ToDictionary` part. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can get Dictionary from LINQ query also by casting it :

```
var d2 = (Dictionary<string, string>)q;
```

This worked on Visual Studio 2013.